# node server only loads on safari localhost and not chrome's

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular7

Node server using http://localhost:8000 only works in Safari but not Chrome. Using 127.0.0.1:8000 would work on both safari and chrome. I'm confused why using localhost will not work in my chrome browser.
Typed in my terminal ping localhost and got 127.0.0.1

Before updating to angular 8 my project was working fine and was able to run it on my localhost. I had some problems after updating so I decided to downgrade back to angular 7. Ever since then I'm only able to run my project using my IP address and my localhost but only using Safari, not Chrome. Any idea what's the problem or how to fix this?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongooseDatabase = require("./server/config/mongoose");
const userRoutes = require('./server/config/routes/users');
const taskRoutes = require('./server/config/routes/tasks');

//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/todo'));

app.use(session({
    secret:"thisisasecret",
    saveUninitialized:true,
    resave:false,
    cookie: {maxAge:1000}
}))
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
mongoose.connect(mongooseDatabase.database, { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser:true });

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log("Connected to database " + mongooseDatabase.database);
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log("Database database " + err);
})


app.use('/users', taskRoutes, userRoutes);
taskRoutes(app);
userRoutes(app);

app.all("*", (req,res,next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve("./dist/todo/index.html"))
});


app.listen(8000, () => console.log("Running on port 8000"));
```

Global version

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.3.4
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.13.4
@angular-devkit/core         7.3.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.3.4
@schematics/angular          7.3.4
@schematics/update           0.13.4
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.4
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^3.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.15",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 7.3.3.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

If you need anymore code/questions lmk.

angular/cli local project version

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.3.4
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.4
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.4
@angular/material                 6.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.4
@schematics/update                0.13.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAXdM.png)
[Error network page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhgN2.png)

Comment: What happens when you run `ng serve`?

Comment: It would automatically open in Chrome, but when I open it in safari it works fine.

Comment: so no errors? whats the issue?

Comment: Bad request, 400 which is only on chrome and nothing with Safari

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: can you screenshot your network tab also? where is it failing

Comment: I wonder if I'm the only one with this problem. I've been searching and a lot of ppl are having problems with their app only working on Safari and not Chrome which is opposite than my problem

Comment: It doesn't show anything on the network tab

Comment: have you changed angular.json file?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything in that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through old posts and have finally figured it out thanks to @Dave E. His [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1159862/when-why-would-chrome-get-500-error-on-localhost-but-load-ok-from-127-0-0-1-whi) explains everything

Answer (score 0):

One If your application is **Node JS**:-

From your server.js code It looks like you have Node JS application. Not Angular application. I don't see any component here. Just press F5 and see what happen ?

After Press F5, open chrome and type http://localhost:8000. It should call your get method from your server.js.

Two If your application is "**Angular**" :-

Can you please add **Debugger for Chrome** as extension in Visual Studio Code ?

Once you add you can open the application in the Chrome by press F5.

When press F5 It will ask you target select Chrome and it will create launch.js in your project. Then add website url in the configuration.

Following is the sample.

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Try this out. Hopefully It should work in your scenario.

Comment: @PushkarGreat debugger extension. So it says : 
```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. core.js:16829 
```
This project has always been running in development mode so I'm confused.

Comment: This is just an instruction. You need not to switch to production. You switch to production by changing the environment in the env.json file If you have. Btw are you able to see your angular application in chrome or not ?

Comment: Also you check enableProduction option under your main.ts file code like if (environment.production) {  enableProdMode();}. And there is folder environments. File environment.ts where you enable disable production mode.

Comment: Yes, I was able to see my angular application run on chrome like how I intended it to

Comment: Do you think maybe it could be a certain version of node or angular/cli that doesn't support one or the other?

Comment: I just noticed something. If you look at the global version compared to the local version it's different. Could that be a factor of why my app isn't running like it did before?

Comment: I don't think so that could be the reason. If above solution works for you, you can mark it as answer so that it will helpful to other who has similar issue like you have.

Comment: @P.Rathod Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem :-/

Comment: @K.Pham You're not able to run the angular project ? What is error ?

Comment: @K.Pham Kindly elaborate your error please. It will help to under the problem,

Comment: @P.Rathod The error that I get is what i posted. Everything in my angular project works. Components work, routing works, no errors or red flags on html, validations work. The only problem is when I use Chrome to start my project starting with http://localhost:<port number> it will not work and gives me an error which I took a screenshot of. Now if I use http://127.0.0.1:<port number> on chrome it works.

Comment: @K.Pham Kindly uninstall & install chrome browser. Remove or disable extension If any. Also kind go to this path. C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc and open hosts file. See localhost name resolution in this file. It should be like this 127.0.0.1       localhost